# Graph created outside of function, not created inside

Tags: r

Somewhat new to R, and I think I may be misunderstanding how functions in R work. When I write this code:

```
past_annual <- past_day %>% 
group_by(year) %>% 
summarize(annual_avg = mean(runoff_daily, na.rm = TRUE))

future_annual <- future_day %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarize(annual_avg_45 = mean(runoff_daily_45, na.rm = TRUE),
              annual_avg_85 = mean(runoff_daily_85, na.rm = TRUE))

ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = past_annual, aes(x = year, y = annual_avg),
              color = "gray60") +
    geom_line(data = future_annual, aes(x = year, y = annual_avg_45),
              color = "turquoise4") +
    geom_line(data = future_annual, aes(x = year, y = annual_avg_85),
              color = "darkgoldenrod3") +
    theme_minimal()
```

It produces a graph [runoff_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qbci.png)

But when I try to write it into a function, it produces a blank graph.

```
plot_annual = function(.y, .x, .z) {
  
  past_annual <- past_day %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarize(annual_avg = mean(.y, na.rm = TRUE))
  
   future_annual <- future_day %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarize(annual_avg_45 = mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
              annual_avg_85 = mean(.z, na.rm = TRUE))
  
  annual_graph <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(data = past_annual, 
              aes(x = year, y = annual_avg),
              color = "gray60") +
    geom_line(data = future_annual, 
              aes(x = year, y = annual_avg_45),
              color = "turquoise4") +
    geom_line(data = future_annual, 
              aes(x = year, y = annual_avg_85),
              color = "darkgoldenrod3") +
    theme_minimal()
  
  return(annual_graph)
}

plot_annual("runoff_daily", "runoff_daily_45", "runoff_daily_85")
```

[function_graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy3Eg.png)

What am I missing here? I copied the code directly from inside the function and replaced the variables with what I want in there, so I'm very confused. Also, this is my first stack overflow post, so apologies if I'm missing some critical information to answer my question.

Comment: You'll need to provide an example that fully reproduces the problem you're experiencing. It's unclear how your function uses its arguments, or whether the function, as used, has access to the `past_day` dataset.

Comment: I think the problem is actually how `.y`, `.x`, `.z` are used in the function. They will require some kind of tidyeval thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is more on how you are using your function arguments. Consider the following:

```r
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(avg_1 = mean(Sepal.Length),
            avg_2 = mean(Sepal.Width))

  Species    avg_1 avg_2
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa      5.01  3.43
2 versicolor  5.94  2.77
3 virginica   6.59  2.97
```

Notice how `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` are not within a double quotation. This is based on special features of how `dplyr` and the `tidyverse` in general can work.

Now try this:

```r
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarize(avg_1 = mean("Sepal.Length"),
            avg_2 = mean("Sepal.Width"))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    avg_1 avg_2
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa        NA    NA
2 versicolor    NA    NA
3 virginica     NA    NA

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default("Sepal.Length") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default("Sepal.Length") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default("Sepal.Length") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default("Sepal.Width") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default("Sepal.Width") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
6: In mean.default("Sepal.Width") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Doesn't work. This is effectively what your function is doing.

```r
f <- function(.x, .y) {
  iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarize(avg_1 = mean(.x),
              avg_2 = mean(.y))
}

f("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    avg_1 avg_2
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa        NA    NA
2 versicolor    NA    NA
3 virginica     NA    NA

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default("Sepal.Length") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default("Sepal.Length") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default("Sepal.Length") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default("Sepal.Width") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default("Sepal.Width") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
6: In mean.default("Sepal.Width") :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

To get around this is actually pretty simply, but a bit more advanced. You can read some about it here, which will explain it much better than I can: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html.

But for now, here is what should work. I cannot reproduce your example, but you can apply the same concept.

```r
f <- function(.x, .y) {
  .x <- rlang::ensym(.x)
  .y <- rlang::ensym(.y)
  
  iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarize(avg_1 = mean(!!.x),
              avg_2 = mean(!!.y))
}

f("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    avg_1 avg_2
  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 setosa      5.01  3.43
2 versicolor  5.94  2.77
3 virginica   6.59  2.97
```

Another option is to use the `.data` pronoun which is implied within `dplyr`.

```r
f <- function(.x, .y) {
  iris %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    summarize(avg_1 = mean(.data[[.x]]),
              avg_2 = mean(.data[[.y]]))
}
```